# How to get text from <td> and then convert it to a decimal

Tags: jquery, html-table, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get the values of my  where the values get generated based on the query parameters and what matches to it in the database. The numbers that get outputted are in decimal form and I need to be able to limit them to two decimal places. So I need to be able to get all of the values at once and then change the text to two decimal places. However, sometimes, not all of the  tags will be filled if there isnt any matching data in the database.

Like this query here returns (this is a console.log of id="decimal")

```
                                             <tr id="decimal">
                                                <th scope="row">%</th>
                                                <td>0.07456508908031056</td>
                                                <td>0.03188519669899027</td>
                                                <td>0.14962427856611382</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>0.12195121951219512</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
```

and not every  is filled.

How do I get the value (if any) from the <td's> and convert them to two decimal places?

This is the HTML. each  is a query and I'm outputting it with handlebars, so sometimes the database wont have a value for certain items.

```
                                   <table class="table text-light text-end">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th scope="col">CHW</th>
                                                <th scope="col">ELE</th>
                                                <th scope="col">STM</th>
                                                <th scope="col">HHW</th>
                                                <th scope="col">GAS</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Dom Water</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Peak CHW</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Maintenance</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Miscuellaneous</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Ann Cash Flow</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Payback</th>
                                                <th scope="col">NPV</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="text-end">
                                            <tr id="decimal">
                                                <th scope="row">%</th>
                                                {{#with chw}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with ele}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with stm}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with hhw}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with gas}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with water}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with peakchw}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                                {{#with labor}}
                                                <td>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{else}}
                                                <td></td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your jQuery that demonstrates your best attempt to resolve this yourself, and explain at what point in your code it's not giving you the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the answer I gave you earlier using `text(function)` just do some checks on current text. The method will iterate over all matching selectors and treat each instance separately

Something like:

```js
$('td').text(function(i, curr) {
  let num = +curr.trim();
  return !curr || isNaN(num) ? curr : num.toFixed(2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">%</th>
    <td>0.07456508908031056</td>
    <td>0.03188519669899027</td>
    <td>0.14962427856611382</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.12195121951219512</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```